# starting embedded youtube video from a specific time

Tags: ios, xcode, youtube

```
        NSString *linkVideo = @"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XabyZDSzMJ0&t=0m38s";
    NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<iframe width=\"420\" height=\"315\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/XabyZDSzMJ0\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>", linkVideo];
    // Load the html into the webview
    [self.myWebView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

Hi, I've embedded a youTube video in my iPhone app.
How can I force starting this video from sec 38th?

thanks a lot!

Comment: You need more tags: language (Objective-C?), platform (iOS?), etc. to get a knowledgeable answer.

Answer (score 1):

Im not a expert and probly wrong but i think &t=0m38s" is for embeded video links, you might have to use &start=38".
"start=" only takes seconds also

Im probly wrong but worth a try

Comment: Hi, i've tried both:
in *linkvideo and/or in *htmlString strings, but it doesn't works :(

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *linkVideo = @"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XabyZDSzMJ0&start=38";
```

This starts the youtube video at the 38th second.

Answer (score 0):

I think this ight be useful: 
http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/link-to-youtube-minute-second/
Thnx,